# Get exchange rates - help me update URL in Excel VBA code that used to work

Tags: html, excel, vba, url, web-scraping

I was using this VBA code that was working, now the function returns 0 because the URL has changed.
What URL should I use now?

Thank you very much.

```
Function YahooCurrencyConverter(ByVal strFromCurrency, ByVal strToCurrency, Optional ByVal strResultType = "Value")
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Init
Dim strURL As String
Dim objXMLHttp As Object
Dim strRes As String, dblRes As Double

Set objXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
strURL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=c4l1&s=" & strFromCurrency & strToCurrency & "=X"

'Send XML request
With objXMLHttp
    .Open "GET", strURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
    .Send
    strRes = .ResponseText
End With

'Parse response
dblRes = Val(Split(strRes, ",")(1))

Select Case strResultType
    Case "Value": YahooCurrencyConverter = dblRes
    Case Else: YahooCurrencyConverter = "1 " & strFromCurrency & " = " & dblRes & " " & strToCurrency
End Select

CleanExit:
    Set objXMLHttp = Nothing

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    YahooCurrencyConverter = 0
    GoTo CleanExit
End Function
```

Comment: I believe access to yahoo.finance in this manner has been discontinued.  I suggest you look at other sources for currency conversion information. [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/) seems to have a well-documented API that should be able to do what you require.  But there are others.

Comment: Heres a sample url for gbp-usd `"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GBPUSD=X?p=GBPUSD=X&.tsrc=fin-srch"` It looks like some things have changed. You can submit XML Request for page and parse the XML response (i.e. looking for id/tag holding text value of exchange rate) For this you will need to edit your `strURL = ...` line and add a part to parse for the `id` or `tag`

Comment: Hi, and thank you.  I've had a look at Alpha Vantage and I must use this  `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=EUR&to_currency=USD&apikey=xxxxxxxxxx`   it returns this ` {
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "EUR",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "Euro",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "USD",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "1.15247200",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2018-10-06 17:13:29",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    }
}`

Comment: How can I get "5. Exchange Rate" value in VBA?

Comment: I'll provide some suggestions in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Split:**

Now you have obtained the JSON string you can parse with Split function. Here I am reading the JSON in the comments from a cell

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetExchangeRate()
    Dim json As String
    json = [A1]
    Debug.Print Split(Split(json, """5. Exchange Rate"": ")(1), ",")(0)
End Sub
```

---

**JSON Parser:**

Here you can use a JSON parser, [JSONConverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and then add a reference via VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Dictionary

```
Public Sub GetRate()
    Dim jsonStr As String, json As Object
    jsonStr = [A1]
    Debug.Print JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr)("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate")("5. Exchange Rate")
End Sub
```

This is the path to your desired change rate:

[image]

The initial object is a dictionary containing another dictionary. Dictionaries are denoted by `{}`. You access the first dictionary with the key `Realtime Currency Exchange Rate`  and then the required value, from the inner dictionary, by the associated key: `5. Exchange Rate`

---

**Whole request with JSON parser:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetRate2()
    Dim URL As String, json As String, http As Object
    URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=EUR&to_currency=USD&apikey=yourAPIkey"
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        json = .responseText
    End With
    Debug.Print JsonConverter.ParseJson(json)("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate")("5. Exchange Rate")
End Sub
```

---

As an UDF:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Debug.Print CurrencyConverter("EUR", "USD")
End Sub

Public Function CurrencyConverter(ByVal FromCurrency, ByVal ToCurrency) As String
    Dim URL As String, json As String, http As Object
    URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=" & FromCurrency & "&to_currency=" & ToCurrency & "&apikey=yourAPIkey"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        json = .responseText
    End With
    CurrencyConverter = JsonConverter.ParseJson(json)("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate")("5. Exchange Rate")
'CurrencyConverter = Replace$(JsonConverter.ParseJson(json)("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate")("5. Exchange Rate"), Application.DecimalSeparator, ".") 
End Function
```

To use split function replace penultimate function line with

```
CurrencyConverter = Replace$(Split(Split(json, """5. Exchange Rate"": ")(1), ",")(0), Chr$(34), vbNullString)
```

Comment: @QHarr Thank you again! It was what I really needed!

Comment: Hi Qharr, I asked you a question in our chat.

Answer (score 0):

Using a JSON parser:

```
Option Explicit
Function EURtoUSD() As Currency
    Const myAPI As String = "apikey=your_key"
    Const sURL As String = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=EUR&to_currency=USD&"
    Const DOL As Currency = 1
    Dim httpRequest As WinHttpRequest
    Dim strJSON As String, JSON As Object

Set httpRequest = New WinHttpRequest
With httpRequest
    .Open "Get", sURL & myAPI
    .send
    .WaitForResponse
    strJSON = .responseText
End With
Set httpRequest = Nothing

Set JSON = ParseJson(strJSON)

EURtoUSD = JSON("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate")("5. Exchange Rate") * DOL

End Function
```

Or, you could used Power Query to set up a refreshable data connection

You can set up the Query in the UI by entering the URL.
After you run it, edit the query by

- convert to table

  - expand the table selecting only the columns you want to keep
  - deselect the option to use the original column name

After you do this, you can refresh the query whenever you want with a single button press.

This is the M-code generated by the UI. I chose to also keep the Time Updated column:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?" & "function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE" & "&from_currency=EUR" & "&to_currency=USD" & "&apikey=your_api")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value", {"5. Exchange Rate", "6. Last Refreshed"}, {"5. Exchange Rate", "6. Last Refreshed"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Value",{{"5. Exchange Rate", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: Hi and thank you. I tried Function EURtoUSD() but I get compilation error, Dim httpRequest As WinHttpRequest not defined. In VBE I tried adding Reference to Microsoft XML 3.0, then 6.0 and also Microsoft HTML Object library, still getting that error. Also tried adding reference to WinHTTP.dll in systems32 but it gives me error "impossible to add reference to specified file" (actual error could be a little bit different, I have Windows 10 in Italian language).

Comment: @Dolphin975 What I have listed is `Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1` with location `C:\Windows\system32\winhttpcom.dll`  Or you could just use late-binding as in your original script `Dim objXMLHttp As Object:Set objXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")`  or possibly `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`